# ThreadPoolExecutor#execute. How to reuse running threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I used to use ThreadPoolExecutors for years and one of the main reasons - it is designed to 'faster' process many requests because of parallelism and 'ready-to-go' threads (there are other though).

Now I'm stuck on minding inner design well known before.
Here is snippet from java 8 ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    ...
    /*
     * Proceed in 3 steps:
     *
     * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
     * start a new thread with the given command as its first
     * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
     * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
     * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
     */
    ...
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
...
```

I'm interested in this very first step as in most cases you do not want thread poll executor to store 'unprocessed requests' in the internal queue, it is better to leave them in external input Kafka topic / JMS queue etc. So I'm usually designing my performance / parallelism oriented executor to have zero internal capacity and 'caller runs rejection policy'. You chose some sane big amount of parallel threads and core pool timeout not scare others and show how big the value is ;). I don't use internal queue and I want tasks to start to be processed the earlier the better, thus it has become 'fixed thread pool executor'. Thus in most cases I'm under this 'first step' of the method logic.

Here is the question: is this really the case that it will not 'reuse' existing threads but will create new one each time it is 'under core size' (most cases)? Would it be not better to 'add new core thread only if all others are busy' and not 'when we have a chance to suck for a while on another thread creation'? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I can't possibly be the only one who read DeadPoolExecutor

Comment: Your under the first step only if your "corePoolSize" is insanely big (greater than the number of requests that you ever process). This is because the worker count is incremented for every started worker (and only decremented if threads are stopped)

Comment: I'm under first step because load is constantly 'waving' and waiting threads exit because of 'core threads timeout'. Moreover the load is usually not that big that would require all core threads creation. So I can see this picture: out of 20 core threads it is using 10 and for each new submit it creates new thread, old ones exit because of timeout.

Comment: Don't really understand the question - of _course_ it will create them - if the core threads don't exist _someone_ has to create then. When the threads are all busy, and you are under the max count it will also create a new thread. The difference is, core threads live until the pool closes and the other threads have an idle timeout.

Comment: It is usually wise to vote up/down after you understand the point...

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) describes the relationship between the corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, and the task queue, and what happens when a task is submitted.

*...but will create new one [thread] each time it is 'under core size...'*

Yes.  From the doc:

> When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), and fewer
>   than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to
>   handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.

*Would it be not better to add new core thread only if all others are busy...*

Since you don't want to use the internal queue this seems reasonable.  So set the corePoolSize and maxPoolSize to be the same.  Once the ramp up of creating the threads is complete there won't be any more creation.

However, using CallerRunsPolicy would seem to hurt performance if the external queue grows faster than can be processed.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the question: is this really the case that it will not 'reuse' existing threads but will create new one each time it is 'under core size' (most cases)?

Yes that is how the code is documented and written.

> Am I missing anything?

Yes, I think you are missing the whole point of "core" threads.  Core threads are defined in the [`Executors` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) are:

```
... threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.
```

That's the definition.  Thread startup is a non trivial process and so if you have 10 core threads in a pool, the first 10 requests to the pool each start a thread until all of the core threads are live.  This spreads the startup load across the first X requests.  This is not about getting the tasks done, this is about initializing the TPE and spreading the thread creation load out.  You could call `prestartAllCoreThreads()` if you don't want this behavior.

The whole purpose of the core threads is to have threads already started and running available to work on tasks immediately.  If we had to start a thread each time we needed one, there would be unnecessary resource allocation time and thread start/stop overhead taking compute and OS resources.  If you don't want the core threads then you can let them timeout and pay for the startup time.

> I used to use ThreadPoolExecutors for years and one of the main reasons - it is designed to 'faster' process many requests because of parallelism and 'ready-to-go' threads (there are other though).

TPE is not necessarily "faster".  We use it because to *manually* manage and communicate with a number of threads is hard and easy to get wrong.  That's why the TPE code is so powerful.  It is the OS threads that give us parallelism.

> I don't use internal queue and I want tasks to start to be processed the earlier the better,

The entire point of a threaded program is the maximize throughput.  If you run 100 threads on a 4 core system and the tasks are CPU intensive, you are going to pay for the increased context switching and the overall time to process a large number of requests is going to decrease.  Your application is also most likely competing for resources on the server with other programs and you don't want to cause it to slow to a crawl if 100s of jobs try to run in a thread pool at the same time.

The whole point of limiting your core threads (i.e. *not* making them a "sane big amount") is that there is an optimal number of concurrent threads that will maximize the overall throughput of your application.  It can be really hard to find the optimal core thread size but experimentation, if possible, would help.

It depends highly on the degree of CPU versus IO in a task.  If the tasks are making remote RPC calls to a slow service then it might make sense to have a large number of core threads in your pool.  If they are predominantly CPU tasks, however, you are going to want to be closer to the number of CPU/cores and then queue the rest of the tasks.  Again it is all about overall throughput.

Comment: This is why it is called 'sane big amount' to imply 'limiting the count and context switches', but I've explaned this in 3 words and you did the same in 3 paragraphs

Comment: I didn't miss the point of 'core threads' my question is why TPE is not optimized and when you have 'idle' core threads it will preffer creating new one to execute the task but not reuse existing one.

Comment: Because you aren't understanding what 'core threads' are and how they work.  The only reason why it starts a new core thread with each request is to spread out the CPU required to initialize the TPE like I said @MykhayloAdamovych.  It's not about getting the job done.  It's about initializing the TPE.  I've made this more plain in my answer.

Comment: And what is wrong with my answer that it requred a -1?

Comment: Also, my answers are writing for posterity for others.  That's the point of SO.  It's not just to address your specific post.

Comment: You are so confident about 'only reasons'... What if my load 'half oh the time' require 5 threads and half of the time 30 threads? What 'core size' will you take? If you take 5 it will work not optimal on high load because it will grab your memory extending queue and will be 'too lazy to execute your tasks', if you take 30 it will be not optimal because in half of the time it will spend on 'context switches too much' and not on doing it's job, if you take 'in the middle' it will be not optimal for both cases. And the load 'waves'...

Comment: What is your option? Home-made, not readable, not supportable, error prone your own extended thread pool executor implementation? Would it be not better just to change the way how 'core threads' are initialized (prefer to reuse, not to create new), which will solve the issue (and keep other features) and needed functionality would be achieved by 4 clean lines of understandable code that utilizes only library implementation? If you understand what 'core threads' are, you should be focusing on this in your answer because this is what question is all about.

Comment: And I also don't like when somebody downgrade you answer 'with no reason' just because 'it is different', are you saying you didn't do the same few days ago?

Comment: Different is not a good reason.  You can take a look at the different solutions on my previous answer dude.  I did not think that it was correct or added any additional information to the discussion.  Best of luck!

Comment: One more thing dude.  You look to be a kid in our just out of college while I'm a SE with 30+ years of experience.  That doesn't make me necessarily right and you are free to disagree but to me you seem to not be listening or even considering input from someone more experienced than you.  I bet this isn't the first time.  Remember to keep an open mind, accept criticism without getting defensive or bitter, and always keep learning.  I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: As I understood there were left no arguments if you started to talk about 'experience'. Try to find some 'arguments' out of you 30+ years of experience. Who is not listening? You said 'different is not a good reason' and I said the same 'and I also don't like... [it]' just before. You said 'optimal number of concurrent threads' and I said the same 'SANE big amount'. I said 'I don't use internal queue' meaning there is no reason to take tasks from input queue and fill your memory and you replying off topic about threads count. You said 'TPE is not necessarily "faster". We use it because...'

Comment: and I said the same 'it is designed ... for parallelism, but THERE ARE OTHER [reasons] THOUGH'. So who is not listening? You just repeated all I said in the question and accuse me I'm not listening? I've repeated question 3 times for you (in a question and twice in comments. Let me repeat you one more time but I don't have much expectation about your 'listening to the question'.

Comment: You are saying 'If you don't want the core threads then you can let them timeout and pay for the startup time' and I'm asking you 'why it was designed not optimal way and why I need to pay more than required? Because I 'pay each time new task arrive' but it could be designed 'to pay only when new task arrive and all threads are busy'? Which is critical for me as load is 'waving'. I will not repeat question again...

Comment: And how can you say about 'accepting criticism' as you did the same (I'm repeating this second time) few days ago and downgraded my answer with 'no reason', just because it was 'different'? During 7.5 years on SO I downgraded ONLY 4 times (up-voted 1000+). I downgrade you because of you standpoint of being '30+ years experienced cool guy' expecting from other conduct which you yourself don't show.

Answer (score -1):

To reuse threads one need somehow to transfer task to existing thread.
This pushed me towards synchronous queue and zero core pool size.

```
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, maxThreadsCount,
        10L, SECONDS,
        new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
        new BasicThreadFactory.Builder().namingPattern("processor-%d").build());
```

I have really reduced amounts of 'peaks' of 500 - 1500 (ms) on my 'main flow'.
But this will work only for zero-sized queue. For non-zero-sized queue question is still open.

Comment: This neither answers the question nor provides any useful information. Without, as you mention above, using a rejected execution policy that executes on the current thread this does little, if anything, of any use. What you instead do is block the current thread whilst waiting for a worker to pick up the task - so it does apply back pressure (which is good), but it wastes work (which is bad).

Comment: I was trying to do with 'core threads' what they were not designed for. But desired functionality is achieved with 'overflow threads'. This is why this partially answers the question and useful. Blocking client threads is not a big deal for me as 'sane big amount' of TPE threads count mean that data will not be processed much faster having more processing threads usually 'caller runs policy' is about not to produce 'overflow errors' and loose tasks. My main concern was 'constant threads creation' under 'normal load' and I've fixed the issue.